# Terminology question about a weaker condition than normal crossings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be an algebraic set (say over $\mathbb C$). From what I understand, we say that $X$ has simple normal crossings if at every point it locally looks like a union of hyperplanes in general position in coordinates.

Is there a standard name for the condition where you remove the "general position" part ? For example, the union of the lines $x_1=0$, $x_2=0$ and the conic $x_1+x_2+x_2^2=0$ would satisfy this condition at $(0,0)$, but would not have simple normal crossings there.